# Visual Studio - Run the project outside of Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

The project runs okay in the debug mode of Visual Studio, but when I tried to double-click the exe generated, it says some dll is missing. When I copied the missing dll beside the exe and double-click again, no error message dialog appeared but also nothing happened(the project has Qt-based GUI and reference some external png files).

How does Visual Studio run the exe ? How can I run the exe on my own ? Should I create a installer for the project to make it run on other computers?

Comment: Try to build the solution in release mode. You will find the exe file in bin\Release all libraries and files you need from your project should be in this folder too. So when moving it to other computers don't forget to copy them too.

Comment: Working directory is properly set in VS. That's why you can run it from the VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a process needs to load a DLL by name (without a full path to it), it will check several different places.  One of those places may be the current working directory.  (The details of the search path are complicated by history and security issues.  You can learn the details by looking up [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SetDllDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.)

In Visual Studio, if you look at the Properties page for the project, and click the Debugging tab, you'll see what directory is set as the working directory when you launch the program from Visual Studio.  When you double click on an icon, I believe the working directory will be the directory of the executable file.  If these are different, that could explain why you're able to find the DLL in one case but not in the other.

If you're calling LoadLibrary directly, the best thing to do is to always give the full path to the library.  Typically, you GetModuleFileName to find out the full path for the executable, then replace the filename portion with the name of the DLL or a relative path from the executable to the DLL.

If you're failing to load an implicitly-linked DLL, then you probably need to make sure your DLL is in the same directory as the executable file.

Answer (score 1):

you would need to either build statically or provide the required dll files.

the page at http://www.tapkaa.com/2013/05/what-dll-files-are-required-to-run-an-application-developed-with-visual-c/ tells how you can find the missing dll files.